# Can I use music-related soundcards to record ultrasounds (providing the sampling frequency is high enough)?

Tags: recording, hardware, mammals, rodents, ultrasounds

I'd like to record rodent ultrasounds (~40-120 kHz) with a soundcard initially made to deal with human-related sounds. The sampling frequency can be adjusted accordingly, however, the microphone/line inputs are described as "+0 -0.1 dB, 20 Hz/20 kHz".
I'd like to know whether this description only implies that the frequency response stability is limited to ±0.1 dB in this frequency range or whether the input impedance will also be small above 20 kHz, i.e. that it is not a good idea to record ultrasound via these inputs.

Have someone tried to record such high frequencies with an appropriately-sensitive microphone plugged to such basic "music-based" soundcard? For now, I don't have a microphone sensitive to such frequencies to test it.

Answer (score 4):

There are thousands of different makes and models of things that might be considered a 'music-based soundcard'. However, the response of the device at high frequencies really depends on the specific hardware and manufacture of the device.

Fortunately for you, with a bit of googling, I've found an existing community of people at [www.audiosciencereview.com](https://www.audiosciencereview.com) who like to empirically and quantitatively test music equipment. You can find their reviews of many 'music-based' sound cards under the ADC/DAC (analog-to-digical converters) sections. Check out the link to their [review database](https://www.audiosciencereview.com/forum/index.php?pages/Reviews/), and then click on the heading for 'Audio Electronics' and then search for 'ADC' to focus on sound cards.

Many, if not most/all of the reviews include noise spectrum at various sample rates, including where applicable 96 and 192 kHz -- which I believe are the most common 'ultrasonic' sampling rates on such devices, though a select few may go even higher.

So, if you've got a specific device in mind/hand for this work, you might be able to find a review with an empirically measured noise floor already online. And if you don't already have a device in mind, then perhaps these reviews will help you find one that suitably meets your requirements?

Comment: Very useful and may answer a lot of related questions

Comment: Thanks @BrianMiller, this site is very useful, I didn't know some people were making reviews with more details than the manufacturer!! Unfortunately, for my soundcards (Focusrite Scarlett 18i8, Scarlett Solo, MOTU STAGE), either there is no review or the measured frequency responses of the interface inputs are limited to the human hearing range.